# Excel - Worksheet Value Lookup Based On ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets. The first lists my customers:

```
A          |B            |C
CustomerID |CustomerName |DateLastProject
MC001      |Ron Bolles   |
MC002      |Neal Pearl   |
MC003      |Meg Black    |
```

On my second worksheet, I list the projects done for the customers (with the date):

```
A          |B            |C
CustomerID |ProjectID    |Date
MC001      |MP112        |01/03/2013
MC002      |MP113        |01/08/2013
MC003      |MP114        |01/08/2013
MC001      |MP115        |01/15/2013
MC003      |MP129        |02/04/2013
```

I need to look up the last project date for each customer and display it in column C of the customers worksheet. So the customers would appear:

```
A          |B            |C
CustomerID |CustomerName |DateLastProject
MC001      |Ron Bolles   |01/15/2013
MC002      |Neal Pearl   |01/08/2013
MC003      |Meg Black    |02/04/2013
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, what have you tried, and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the array formula for this.

[image]

And the formula is:
**=MAX(IF(A2=F2:F6;H2:H6;""))**

BUT you will need to apply it as a ARRAY FORMULA, so when you enter the above formula:
Push the ctrl + shift as you hit the enter button. And the formula will be shown as:
**{=MAX(IF(A2=F2:F6;H2:H6;""))}**

> And if you have two sheets, the formula will be

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2:A6;Sheet2!C2:C6;""))
```

(Remember to enter F2 and hold down ctrl + shift and then hit enter button and it will be an array formula as: **{=MAX(IF(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2:A6;Sheet2!C2:C6;""))}**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting a formula error every time I try to enter it. When I hit ok on the error message, the first A6 is selected in the formula.

Comment: Try to replace the ; in the function with , instead